# Ruby Class definition explanation for a java developer

Tags: java, ruby, oop

I am a java developer and am having hard time understanding this Ruby code, can someone please explain this code in java terms? I can understand the methods part (defs) but the belongs_to part is what confusing me

```
module Test

  class Signature < Base
    belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'Test::UserInformation'
    belongs_to :sd_file, :class_name => 'Test::TransportFile',
                                         :foreign_key => 'reference_id'

    def sd_status
      sd_file.nil? ? nil : sd_file.Status
    end

    def sd_sent_on
      sd_file.nil? ? nil : sd_file.sent
    end

    def sd_received_on
      sd_file.nil? ? nil : sd_file.received
    end

    def self.find_information(options={})
      unless (start_date = options.delete(:start_date)).blank? ||
               (end_date   = options.delete(:end_date)).blank?
          date_conditions = ' AND '                           +
                            '(requested_at > ?) AND ' +
                            '(requested_at < ?)'            
      end
```

Comment: `belongs_to` is a class method in ruby or in java a static method.  the method signature would look like `def self.belongs_to(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: worth mentioning that `belongs_to` is not in Ruby itself, it's in Rails (ActiveRecord, specifically), and it's probably worth checking [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing here is to realize that (almost) everything in Ruby is a script, (almost) everything in Ruby is a message send ("virtual method call" in Java-speak), and (almost) everything in Ruby is an object.

In Java, the only executable code is inside method definitions. Everything else are just *declarations*, directives to the compiler to create some compiler-internal data structure. A class declaration isn't executed at runtime, it is interpreted at compile time by the compiler, which then generates the corresponding class structure, methods, fields, etc.

Not so in Ruby. The content of a file is just a script that gets executed top to bottom. That's why you can, for example, have stuff like this:

```
if OS.windows?
  class Foo
  end
else
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Likewise, the body of a module or class definition is just a script, which allows you to have stuff like this:

```
if OS.windows?
  def foo
  end
else
  def bar
  end
end
```

So, as you can see, really almost everything is a script, in particular, the body of a class definition is just a script that gets executed from top to bottom, just like any other script.

By the way, since the class definition is dynamically executed at runtime and not statically interpreted by the compiler, the same goes for the superclass definition in a class definition: it is, in fact, just an arbitrary Ruby expression that returns an object that is an instance of [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html), it doesn't necessarily have to be a static constant class, i.e. you can write something like this:

```
class Foo < if rand < 0.5 then String else Array end
end
# Yes, I am aware that this makes zero sense. Here is a more sensible example:

class Point < Struct.new(:x, :y)
end
# `Struct` is a class whose `::new` method returns a class

class Search < R '/search'
end
# This is an example from the Camping web microframework:
# `Search` is a controller which is bound to the URI route `/search`
```

In case you are wondering: if a class definition is just a piece of code, does it return anything? And the answer is "Yes, it does!" In fact, *everything* in Ruby returns something, *everything* is an expression in Ruby. There are no statements. Only expressions. A class definition evaluates to the value of the last expression that is evaluated inside the class definition. Typically, the last expression that is evaluated inside a class definition is a method definition (yes, a method definition is an expression just like any other, and thus also has a return value), and a method definition evaluates to the name of the method being defined, expressed as a [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html)

Also, almost everything is an object: there is a top-level global object which doesn't have a name but is usually called `main` (because that's what its `to_s` and `inspect` return). Everything you run at the top-level in a script happens with `self` (`this` in Java-speak) being bound to `main`. And classes are also objects, they are instances of the `Class` class. Within a class definition body, `self` is bound to the class that is being defined.

Now, on to "almost everything is a message send": usually, whenever you see something being "done" in Ruby, it is the result of a message send: `1 + 2` is actually `1.+(2)`, `!false` is actually `false.!`, `foo.bar = baz` is actually `foo.bar=(baz)`, `ary[idx]` is actually `ary.[](idx)`, `ary[idx] = val` is actually `ary.[]=(idx, val)` and so on and so forth.

[`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) is no different: it is actually a message send to `self`, which in the context of a class definition is the class being defined. In other words, it's just calling a "class method". (Note: there aren't really class methods in Ruby, every method is an instance method. As we have already established, classes are objects like any other object, so they can have instance methods like any other object, there is no need for a special "class method" or "static method" construct!)

Let's start with an easier example:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar
end
```

Again, [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) is a message send to `self`, which is `Foo` in this case. `attr_reader` just generates an attribute reader (a "getter" in Java-speak). And it looks a bit like this (don't worry if you don't fully grasp Ruby Reflection yet, you should be able to follow along anyhow):

```
class Class # in reality, it is defined in `Module`, a superclass of `Class`
  def attr_reader(name)
    define_method(name) do
      instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}")
    end
  end
end
```

By the way: `def` is not a message send, it is a builtin keyword. But there is a corresponding method that can be used instead, which you see being used above: [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method)

In fact, Ruby doesn't even have constructors! [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) is just a "class method", and it looks pretty much like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    new_obj = allocate
    new_obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    return new_obj
  end
end
```

There are a few subtleties here, such as [`initialize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private) being `private` by default, so that in reality we need to use reflection to circumvent access restrictions, but that's the gist of it.

Oh, and since I just mentioned [`private`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private): that's a method, too, not a keyword that is interpreted as an instruction for the compiler.

So, to recap, where do we stand: a class definition is just a piece of code, method definitions are just expressions that get executed. But since a class definition is just a piece of code, there can be arbitrary code in there, including message sends ("method calls" in Java-speak). `belongs_to` is just a message send (method call) to the class itself, i.e. the method is defined somewhere up in the inheritance chain of the class object itself (not to be confused with the inheritance chain of *instances* of the class!)

But the really important takeaway is this: it is just a method call. Nothing scary. Nothing magical. Nothing special.

Now, what does this method call *do*?

It is part of a popular ORM library for Ruby called [*ActiveRecord*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), and it sets up an association between `self` (i.e. the class whose definition the call appears in) and another class whose name is provided as an argument (or to be more precise: since ActiveRecord relies a lot on conventions, the name of the class can be *derived* from the argument). From this association between Ruby classes, the ActiveRecord ORM will automatically deduce corresponding relations between the database tables backing those classes.

Explaining how exactly that works would amount to writing a full tutorial on ActiveRecord, which a) is just too much for a Stack Overflow answer, and b) other people have already done much better than me. But I got the impression anyway that you didn't so much want to know how `belongs_to` works internally, but rather how a method call can appear in what your Java-trained mind is used to being just "dead code" that doesn't get executed. And the solution to that riddle is simply: it isn't dead code and it does get executed.

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` may seem like a very magical piece of ruby code, that connects your model to another, using SQL table associations.

But all it does is takes in a few hash parameters, creating series of dynamic methods.

Lets take  apart

```
belongs_to :sd_file, class_name: 'Test::TransportFile', foreign_key: 'reference_id'
```

`belongs_to` - A methods to set up an association

`sd_file` - What method will be used to acess it:

- `Test::Signature.first.sd_file`

`class_name` - option to specify which ruby class to load. `sd_file` will point to `Test::TransportFile`. Usually this is done automatically by `rails` if everything adheres to conventions. But you can specify manually

`foreign_key` - Key in the table which ties the two records together. This is either in `Test::TransportFile` or in `Test::Signature` (I can't remember off the top of my head). And it will tie in with the `id` in another table.